# Difference between Big O and How fast a Function grows

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity, discrete-mathematics

I seem to be confusing two concepts, asymptotic complexity (How fast a Function Grows), and Big O (The Time Complexity of an algorithm). Are they the same?

For instance, I know that `O(1)` is the best case running time for algorithms. But clearly this grows slower than something like `O(n^n)` which grows extremely quickly, but is not a favorable complexity of an algorithm?

Also something like:
`nlogn` grows faster than `1` or `logn`, but all of those functions grow slower than `n^n`? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Quick growth is bad. You seem to have gotten the idea that it's good. Dunno why.

Comment: Mixture of confusion between two College Classes (Data Structures and Discrete Math), leads to misinterpretations and furthermore, misunderstanding.

Comment: It depends on what you want. If you want to make your algorithm super-slow (e.g. if you want a hashing function that is resistant to rainbow table attacks), fast growth is good. If you want to use fewer resources, it's of course bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is a way to measure asymptotic complexity of an algorithm that may be time or space. From the Wikipedia link:

> A description of a function in terms of big O notation usually only
>   provides an upper bound on the growth rate of the function.

...

> Big O notation is also used in many other fields to provide similar estimates.

There is something to be said for the magnitude of `n` as O(1) is the best complexity though this notes that for large enough `n` the constant terms don't matter.

https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps102/Spring04/TantaloAsymp.pdf may be useful as a way to see different notations that could be used.

Comment: Big O is not necessarily worst case only, simply an upper bound.

Comment: The "upper bound" component of Big O would be an alternate way to express the same point that this is generally used for worst case while other notation exists for other kinds of bounds.

Comment: Sure, my point is that you can have Big O of average case and best case complexity analysis [i.e. for [quicksort](http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/big-o.html)].

Comment: In mathematics you can use big/little O notation to express how a sequence converges to its limit. Big O notation is not bounded to algorithms.

Comment: I'm stating a way to interpret it. There is also Probability theory that uses this notation and other realms too. How would you want that denoted here?